# Where is OkHttpClient cache?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using [OkHttpClient](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html) for the first time. It works very well, is very fast. So I understood that it uses an its own persistent cache, but when I request the folder where resides I receive *null* on `getCache()`. What is my misunderstanding?

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Log.i("CACHE DIRECTORY", httpClient.getCache().getDirectory().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default impl of `OkHttpClient` has no cache. it provides a `setCache` method to customize one's own cache.

Comment: Is it so fast without cache? Very good. Well, if I set my own cache, OkHttpClient will use that automatically?

Comment: I check the source code and the OkhttpClient‘s cache will not function at all, the cache works with another class CachControl. you can refer http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/index.html. see the Cache class .